# TransitionControl using xaml and usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, wpf-controls

I'm trying to use Teleriks RadTransitionControl to transition only a datagrid(partial of the screen) to a usercontrol view, I know I can transition with two usercontrols but is it possible to transition hardcoded xaml to a usercontrol?

For Example:

```
     <telerik:RadTransitionControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="{Binding UserControl1}">
           <Grid>
              <Datagrid ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection></DataGrid>
              <Button content="Go to usercontrol" Command="{Binding TransitionToUserControl1}" />
           </Grid>
     </telerik:RadTransitionControl>
```

In other words, when I select the button "Go to usercontrol", I want to change the content to be a UserControl1. **My problem is I can't set the content twice.** For logic reasons, I can't separate the datagrid and button into another usercontrol, it has to apart of the same view the transitioncontrol is on. Any advice on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

So, try this. Create views in xaml - UserControls. In code-behind create a property:

```
public UserControl MyActualView {get;set;}
```

You should also think about handling events from button:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyActualView = new MyUserControl1();
}
```

I also recommend you to use MVVM pattern, because with is you don't have to handle PropertyChanged event to actualize views. More information about MVVM here http://www.geekchamp.com/news/understanding-mvvm-a-series-of-mvvm-light-toolkit-tutorials

Comment: Not to familiar with ContentControls, how would I actually integrate this into the radtransitioncontrol

Comment: My mistake, forget about my answer. radtransitioncontrol is actually ContentControl. Can you just create Property of UserControl type in codebehind, bind to it just like you did it before (`Content="{Binding Name_of_property}") and change the value of Property by creating new UserControl (the one you want to show) ?